# Is there a way to create a group chat without using a database?

Tags: php, html, css, json, ajax

I'd like to create a group chat, and would like all the messages and there matching usernames to be stored in a JSON file.

However, this looks quite hard to do without using node.js or MySQLi.

As you can see below, i can already read the JSON and display it in "chat-wrap". The problem is to add messages to the json file with PHP and/or AJAX, and update the HTML automatically.

The input is where the user types the message, and I assume i'll have to use JS to notice when ENTER is pressed, because i do not want to use a form (unless you can convince me otherwise).

My HTML:

```
<div class="col chat">
    <div class="messages" id="chat-wrap"> 
        <?php include "chat/chat_process.php"; ?>
    </div>
    <input maxlength='100' type="search" name="type_message" id="type_message" placeholder="Type a message...">
</div>
```

JSON example:

```
{
    "message_list": [{
            "uname": "User 1",
            "text": "Hello everyone!"
        },
        {
            "uname": "User 2",
            "text": "Hey!"
        },
        {
            "uname": "User 1",
            "text": "Hello!"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've already tried messing with the following code, but i'm new to JS and AJAX so ofcourse the code below didn't really work out...

```
$("#type_message").keypress(function (event) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == '13') {

        var msg = $("#type_message").val();
        if (msg.length == 0) {
            alert("Enter a message first!");
            return;
        }

        var name = 'Username';

        var data = {
            uname: name,
            text: msg
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "chat.php",
            data: {
                data: JSON.stringify(data)
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                // display chat data stored in text file 
            }
        });
    }
});
```

When a message is typed and entered, it should add to the JSON file and display it live on every users screen. 
Please excuse me if i forgot to clarify anything, i'm kinda new to stackoverflow and i'm not sure what y'all pros expect to know...
Thanks!

Comment: You should look into websockets, but you'll need some sort of database if you want to show the chat *history* to a newly connected user. "How do I store stuff without a database" is kinda like asking "how do I drive a car with no wheels".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a bit of code to your success function as a result you should be able to add the new text dynamically to your html and also saves the changes to your file messages.json.

```
  $("#type_message").keypress(function(event) {
let keycode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;
if (keycode == "13") {
  let msg = $("#type_message").val();
  if (msg.length == 0) {
    alert("Enter a message first!");
    return;
  }

  let name = "Username";

  let data = {
    uname: name,
    text: msg
  };
  currentjson.push(data); // Also added one global variable which allows you to push the new data into the old json array.
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "chat/chat.php", // I changed the url slightly since i put the php files in another directory
    data: {
      data: JSON.stringify(currentjson)
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
      $(".chat").html("");    // Reset the html of the chat
      addNodes(response); // Add the new Data to the chat by calling addNodesfunction
    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
}
```

Here is the php file that saves the json :

```
<?php
$file = fopen('messages.json','w');
$data = $_POST['data'];
fwrite($file,$data);
fclose($file);
echo $data; // return the new data set
```

addNodes function :

```
function addNodes(messages) {
  for (let message of messages) {
    const chatDiv = $(".chat");
    const user = document.createElement("h3");
    const content = document.createElement("p");
    user.textContent = message.uname;
    content.textContent = message.text;
    chatDiv.append(user);
    chatDiv.append(content);
  }
}
```

I also changed your json to make it a little easier to loop through : (json example)

```
[
  { "uname": "User 1", "text": "Hello everyone!" },
  { "uname": "User 2", "text": "Hey!" },
  { "uname": "User 1", "text": "Hello!" }
]
```

Finally the whole client.js code looks like this :

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  let currentjson = undefined;
  $.ajax("chat/chat_process.php", { // This gets the file the first time the user opens the page
    success: function(data) {
      const messages = JSON.parse(data); 
      currentjson = messages;
      addNodes(currentjson);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("There was some error performing the AJAX call!");
    }
  });

  $("#type_message").keypress(function(event) {
    let keycode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;
    if (keycode == "13") {
      let msg = $("#type_message").val();
      if (msg.length == 0) {
        alert("Enter a message first!");
        return;
      }

      let name = "Username";

      let data = {
        uname: name,
        text: msg
      };
      currentjson.push(data); // Also added one global variable which allows you to push the new data into the old json array.
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "chat/chat.php",
        data: {
          data: JSON.stringify(currentjson)
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
          $(".chat").html("");    // Reset the html of the chat
          addNodes(response); // Add the new Data to the chat by calling addNodesfunction
        },
        error: function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
function addNodes(values) {
  for (let message of values) {
    const chatDiv = $(".chat");
    const user = document.createElement("h3");
    const content = document.createElement("p");
    user.textContent = message.uname;
    content.textContent = message.text;
    chatDiv.append(user);
    chatDiv.append(content);
  }
}
```

But the final tasks that remains is that to display the new data to all the users currently using the website. To be able to do that i think you can use setInterval for like every 5 seconds and call a function which will detect if messages.json was changed  by any user and then updates accordingly.

I hope my answers was useful :)

Comment: I did not do the addNodes part though, but everything else worked perfectly! Thank you for that :) I am now indeed figuring out how to update the chat for every user.
I'm trying Jquery's "load" method, but it skips my foreach loop, which i'm not sure how to fix yet...
Anyway, thanks Laura! ^_^

Comment: Already found a solution!
The following did the trick by adding it to my chat_updater.js:
`setInterval(function(){
        $("#chat-wrap").load(location.href + " #chat-wrap");
      },1000);`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can, if you register the data into a variable or a text file in the server side.

You can trigger actions using server-sent events

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp

PS: someone has done it here:

https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Server-Sent-Events-Simple-Chat-Application-Example

Answer (score -1):

### Update sessions for chat directly

**Advantages**: It's much faster than passing files, storing information in DB. It's far less resource intensive. It avoids a lot of middle-man systems for handling the chat. It doesn't leave you holding onto increasing amounts of data. It avoids a LOT of legal issues with holding onto user data (because you aren't).

**Disadvantages**: You -have- to make sure it's secure in some way that best fits your use case. Also, troubleshooting session switching if something goes wrong can sometimes be a pain in the arse. Not useful if you're wanting to sell user data.

In php, store the information in session data. Then, fire off a child process (unconnected with the current session) that loads the session of the other user, and updates the other user's session data, having each session holding a variable in their session that stores the session IDs of the other users in the chat.

Mychat.php

```
$message = "" // Whatever's said
$groupids = implode(",", $other_users_ids); //Whatever your group's ids are.
$_SESSION["group_chat_users"]["my_id"] = session_id();
$_SESSION["my_chat_log"][]= $message;
exec("php my_group_update.php $groupids $_SESSION["group_chat_users"]["my_id"] $message");
```

my_group_update.php

```
$groupids = explode(",", $argv[1]);
$calling_user = $argv[2];
$message = $argv[3];
foreach ($groupids as $userid){
    session_start($userid);
    $_SESSION["my_chat_log"][]= $message");
}
```

As for outputing the JSON, it's as simple as:

fetch_log.php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($_SESSION["my_chat_log"]);
```

Letting the user have their JSON log without it ever having to touch your Harddrive (or, alternatively, you can write it to your harddrive if you prefer.)

#### Notice: As should go without saying (but apparently needs to be said) As always, validate your inputs. Not doing so will leave you vulnerable to injection.

Ways suggestions on ways to prevent injection:

- Have $message be a temporary file name written in Mychat.php and pulled in my_group_update.php
- Convert $message to a hex string in Mychat.php and converted back in my_group_update.php
- Alter my_group_update to pull the message from the first user's Session before switching to other users where it gets pasted.
- Alert mychat to not include any variables other than the group_id in the exec call. Then have my_group_update just take the group ID, and cycle through all the shared chat session arrays, and find all new values, and update all the chats with it <---(probably the best).
- Spin up a temporary very tiny VM that only handles the 1 chat, (maybe running with alpine linux or similar for a very small size that then self-destructs when the chat finishes.) This would be much higher overhead, but way more secure than anything else you'll even consider doing.

The list goes on.

Comment: This is a terrifying approach and should come with a "seriously this is dangerous" warning. A message of `&& rm -rf /` would blow away the entire server.

Comment: @ceejayoz A good point, but not worth down-voting over as nevertheless, it should work, and with way less overhead than other answers. How to make it secure and how information is validated is a different question entirely.

Comment: "I had to rebuild the entire server after it got compromised/deleted" is quite a bit of overhead.

Comment: @ceejayoz This is a 'how to' question, not a security question. You have to validate all inputs coming in. You'd have to similar if someone posted a question of "How do I Post a post a username to a DB entry?" You'd also have lots of cleaning there, but the majority of answers would still be a simple "INSERT INTO 'users'..." command, and most wouldn't look twice about answers not validating input. I'm not disagreeing that we DO need to validate input; I'm simply stating that we don't generally do that in non-security stackoverflow questions for the purpose of brevity and clarity.

Comment: @ceejayoz To appease you, however, I have added a notice that input should be validated.